# Twitter Search - Multiple searches based on CSV in Text file

Tags: php, twitter

I have a log file which stores search terms I want to run agasint a twitter search.

I have the following which basically searches for 1 value, however the CSV contains a number of values to search.

How can I adjust the below to find the file: searchterms.txt

Read in the comma seperated values, then search each one independantly.

Also save each search to its own text file?

```
<?php

$q=$_GET['q'];

if($_GET['q']==''){

$q = 'tpid1262445133';}

$search = "http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=".$q."";

$tw = curl_init();

curl_setopt($tw, CURLOPT_URL, $search);
curl_setopt($tw, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$twi = curl_exec($tw);
$search_res = new SimpleXMLElement($twi);

foreach ($search_res->entry as $twit1) {
         $description = $twit1->content;
         $date =  strtotime($twit1->updated);
         $message = $row['content'];

echo $twit1->author->uri;
echo "&nbsp;";
echo $twit1->author->name;
echo "&nbsp;";
echo $description;
echo "</br>";
}

curl_close($tw);

?>
```

Comment: Are you asking us to modify the script for you?

Answer (score 1):

```
$searches = explode(';', file_get_contents('searchterms.txt'));
foreach ($searches as $search) {
    $result_array[] = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='.$search));
}
print_r($result_array);
```